# "Share Screen" on Skype link?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, apache-flex

- Is there a way to "share screen" Skype link ?

*// I need to import it both in html page and flex application.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done unfortunately, you can see what CAN be done at this URL:
http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/

Basically a simple **callme** button, or **callme** button with your **current status** (available, busy...).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. It actually answer aswell :)